# Oracle Execution Plan

Tags: sql, oracle, query-optimization

I have table A with following structure

```
create table A {
 id Oracle Execution Plan  primary key,
 value varchar(20)
}
```

and i have the following query:

```
select * from a where id in (123) or id in (select 133 from dual);
```

i get this explain plan:

[image]
Why do we have here table access full ? i mean we are using PK for filtering thus as we know PK is indexed. Furthermore is i change the query to

```
select * from a where id in (123) or id in (55);
```

We have the following exp. plan: 
[image]
So with subquery we have table access full while with out it we have not. Why ?

Answer (score 2):

If you examine the full output from the DBMS_Plan you'll probably find that the second query was transformed to:

```
id in (123,55)
```

... and that the first query was not.

You don't seem to have much data in the table, and the optimiser knows that, so the cost difference between index and full table access methods is extremely small anyway. The optimiser will consider what it believes to be the maximum and minimum values in the id column, and possibly their distribution also, to determine what the likely cardinality of the result set is before choosing a plan.

You have to be really careful to ensure that you are dealing with a genuine data set that you need to optimise queries against -- the optimiser is very difficult to fool with fake date.

Answer (score 2):

> with subquery we have table access full while with out it we have not.

That's because the optimizer does a **predicate rewrite** as **`OR  EXISTS`**. You could see the same in the **filter** in the EXPLAIN PLAN.

`id in (123) or id in (select 133 from dual)` is not the same as `id in (123) or id in (55)` when the optimizer creates an optimal plan for the query execution. The optimizer rewrites the subquery in the predicate.

`or id in (select 133 from dual)` **is rewritten as** `OR  EXISTS (SELECT 0 FROM "SYS"."DUAL""DUAL" WHERE :B1=133))`

For example,

**CASE# 1**

```
SQL> EXPLAIN PLAN FOR
  2  SELECT * FROM emp WHERE empno = 7369 or empno = 7499;

Explained.

SQL>
SQL> SELECT * FROM TABLE(dbms_xplan.display);

PLAN_TABLE_OUTPUT
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Plan hash value: 2355049923

---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation                    | Name   | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT             |        |     2 |    78 |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|   1 |  INLIST ITERATOR             |        |       |       |            |          |
|   2 |   TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID| EMP    |     2 |    78 |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|*  3 |    INDEX UNIQUE SCAN         | PK_EMP |     2 |       |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------


PLAN_TABLE_OUTPUT
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
---------------------------------------------------

   3 - access("EMPNO"=7369 OR "EMPNO"=7499)

15 rows selected.
```

**CASE# 2**

```
SQL> EXPLAIN PLAN FOR
  2  SELECT * FROM emp WHERE empno = 7369 OR empno IN(SELECT 7499 FROM dual);

Explained.

SQL>
SQL> SELECT * FROM TABLE(dbms_xplan.display);

PLAN_TABLE_OUTPUT
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Plan hash value: 3969125370

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation          | Name | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT   |      |     2 |    78 |     3   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|*  1 |  FILTER            |      |       |       |            |          |
|   2 |   TABLE ACCESS FULL| EMP  |    14 |   546 |     3   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|*  3 |   FILTER           |      |       |       |            |          |
|   4 |    FAST DUAL       |      |     1 |       |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------

PLAN_TABLE_OUTPUT
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
---------------------------------------------------

   1 - filter("EMPNO"=7369 OR  EXISTS (SELECT 0 FROM "SYS"."DUAL"
              "DUAL" WHERE :B1=7499))
   3 - filter(:B1=7499)

18 rows selected.
```

So, you see the query is rewritten such that the filter is applied as

```
filter("EMPNO"=7369 OR  EXISTS (SELECT 0 FROM "SYS"."DUAL"
                  "DUAL" WHERE :B1=7499))**
```

Now, let's execute the query which was **rewritten**. After modification:

```
SQL> EXPLAIN PLAN FOR
  2  SELECT * FROM emp
  3  WHERE EMPNO =7369 OR  EXISTS (SELECT 0 FROM DUAL WHERE :B1=7499);

Explained.

SQL>
SQL> SELECT * FROM TABLE(dbms_xplan.display);

PLAN_TABLE_OUTPUT
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
Plan hash value: 2411523692

--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation         | Name | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT  |      |     2 |    78 |     3   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|*  1 |  TABLE ACCESS FULL| EMP  |     2 |    78 |     3   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|*  2 |   FILTER          |      |       |       |            |          |
|   3 |    FAST DUAL      |      |     1 |       |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------


PLAN_TABLE_OUTPUT
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
---------------------------------------------------

   1 - filter("EMPNO"=7369 OR  EXISTS (SELECT 0 FROM "SYS"."DUAL"
              "DUAL" WHERE TO_NUMBER(:B1)=7499))
   2 - filter(TO_NUMBER(:B1)=7499)

17 rows selected.

SQL>
```

So, you can now see that the predicate rewrite and the same modified query has a similar explain plan, and does a **FULL TABLE SCAN**.